# How to highlight same words with shift-8(*) in Atom under Vim-mode?

Tags: atom-editor

This is the effect I am looking for:

[image: example]

Namely I want to highlight all instances of the selected word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually use Vim Mode in Atom, however I get the same effect of highlighting all instances of the selected word with the [highlight-selection](https://atom.io/packages/highlight-selected) package:

[image: Screenshot of Highlight Selection in Action]

I strongly suspect it will work just as well with Vim Mode as it does in normal Atom Mode.

Comment: First, Thanks for your patiently edit about the problem description!!! You are correct. With the highlight-selection package, we can achieve the effect. But it has to use mouse that is not preferable.

Comment: Your right that's not ideal, I can confirm that without `vim-mode` installed and when selecting text from the keyboard with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Right Arrow` does trigger `highlight-selection` to highlight all instances of the selected word, however when selecting a word with `vim-mode` enabled using the keyboard `v`, `a`, `w` the highlights are not selected.  Can I suggest posting this as a feature request on the [highlight-selected issues board](https://github.com/richrace/highlight-selected/issues).